# Is there a way to create a for loop in Google Apps Script that increases every second for a minute?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, timer, spreadsheet, google-docs-api

As of recently I have been working on a project that streams data from a google doc to a google spreadsheet in real time. I have been playing with the Apps Script API and have created a cycle that updates once a minute with the time based triggers method. I'm also aware that Apps Script does not allow a for loop that continues longer than ~5 minutes. So, my theory is that the function that the trigger calls every minute can have a loop that runs for about a minute. The thing is, I can't get a function to run once a second (or even once every 2 or 3 seconds) for a minute. The code below is what I'm using to create this loop, but I can't get it to work. It will either run through the numbers really fast, within a second or two, or will continually run and never stop.

```
function myfunction() {
  let start = new Date().getTime()
  const limit = 60;
  let timeEllapsed = 0
  
  for(i=0; i < 60; i++) {
    let start = new Date().getTime()
    while(true){
     if(start > new Date().getTime + 1000) {
      Logger.log(timeEllapsed)  
      timeEllapsed += 1
      break
   }
  }
}
}
```

How can I fix this so that the for loop will only repeat once per second, and the script will finish running after 60 seconds?

Answer (score 2):

Apps Script has a `sleep()` method that will pause the code:

```
function myfunction() {
  let start = 0;
  var timeEllapsed = 0;
  
  const limit = 60000;
  const increment = 1000;//1000 milliseconds is 1 second
  
  while(timeEllapsed < limit){
    timeEllapsed += increment;
    Utilities.sleep(1000);//Wait for 1 second
  }
  
  Logger.log(timeEllapsed);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

60 Second Timer:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
    <title><b>Output Folder</b></title>
  </head>
  <script>
    var t=0;
    var id='';
    function increment() {
      t+=1;
      check(t);
      document.getElementById('txt1').value=t;
      google.script.run.onSecond(t);//Calls a server side function
    }
    function reset() {
      clearInterval(id);
      t=0;
    }
    function start() {
      id=setInterval(increment,1000);
    }
    function check(t) {
      if(t>=59) {
        reset();
      }
    }
  </script>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="txt1" />
    <br /><input type="button" value="Start" onclick="start();" />
    <br /><input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="reset();" />
  </body>
</html>
```

GAS:

```
function onSecond(t) {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange(1,1).setValue(t);
}

function showTimerDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah1'));
}
```